# Adding variable to each user

Tags: php, laravel-4, foreach

Basically im try to add a variable(which is a value) to each user in this case the value shows a calculation which needs to be done for each user but not sure if its right and how to get that value in the view:

Controller

```
    $users = User::all();
    foreach ($users as $user) {

        // Gets past events assigned to user
        $past_sessions = count(User::pastUserTraining($user->id)->get());
        // Gets past events attended 
        $amount_attended = count(User::amountTraingAttended($user->id)->get());

        // if no past events 
        if($past_sessions == 0){
            $res = 0;
        }
        else{
            $res = ($amount_attended / $past_sessions) * 100;
        }

        //Rounds number to whole number
        $res = round($res);
    }

    // load the view and pass the users with pes(value for each)
    return View::make('attendance.index')
               ->with('users', $users)
               ->with('pes', $res);
}
```

View

```
@foreach($users as $key => $value)
    <tr class="users">
    <td>{{ ucfirst($value->firstName), ' ', ucfirst($value->lastName) }}</td>
    <td>{{ $pes }}<td>
@endforeach
```

So in theory i want it to comeback with

username, Value

username, Value

At the moment it returns

username, same value for all users the last calculation,

i know my methods work as i can show the calculation for an individual just not all on the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it this way using an Accessor;

User Model

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    ...

    public function getPesAttribute(){
        // Gets past events assigned to user
        $past_sessions = count(self::pastUserTraining($this->id)->get());
        // Gets past events attended 
        $amount_attended = count(self::amountTraingAttended($this->id)->get());

        // if no past events 
        if($past_sessions == 0){
            return 0;
        }

        $res = ($amount_attended / $past_sessions) * 100;

        //Rounds number to whole number
        return round($res);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then within your view simply get this data by using `$value->pes;`.

Then you can get rid of it all out of your controller. Like so;

```
$users = User::all();

// load the view and pass the users with pes(value for each)
return View::make('attendance.index')
           ->with('users', $users);
```

**Please Note**: This has not been tested.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this calculation on the user model.

View:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr class="users">
    <td>{{ ucfirst($user->firstName), ' ', ucfirst($user->lastName) }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->attendedRatio() }}<td>
@endforeach
```

On the user model you can do

```
public function attendedRatio() {
    // Gets past events assigned to user
    $past_sessions = User::pastUserTraining($this->id)->count();
    // Gets past events attended 
    $amount_attended = User::amountTraingAttended($this->id)->count();

    // if no past events 
    if($past_sessions == 0){
        return 0
    }

    $ratio = ($amount_attended / $past_sessions) * 100;

    //Rounds number to whole number
    return round($ratio);
}
```

A even better why (faster) would be to use joins using Eloquent hasMany relation and accessing the count. but this is an easy to understand sollution

Comment: how would i set this attribute to be order so top has the best ??